# Webkit GTK: Using the DOM Tree Walker

Tags: c++, c, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

So, I'm experimenting with Webkit GTK DOM functions.  It's pretty straightforward, except for one thing: there's a useful part of the API called the `WebKitDOMTreeWalker` which, I assume, lets you walk over each node in the DOM, just like the `TreeWalker` object in Javascript.

Now, in Javascript a TreeWalker is created by calling:

`document.createTreeWalker(root, nodesToShow, filter, entityExpandBol)`

So, in WebKit GTK, there is an obvious counterpart in the API - a function called `webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker`.  The function signature is:

```
WebKitDOMTreeWalker* webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker(WebKitDOMDocument* self, WebKitDOMNode* root, gulong what_to_show, WebKitDOMNodeFilter* filter, gboolean expand_entity_references, GError **error);
```

So creating a TreeWalker with WebKit GTK seems pretty straightforward - except for one big problem: the fourth argument in the `webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker` expects a ***filter*** object, that is, it wants an instance of `WebKitDOMNodeFilter`.  Well, the Javascript function also takes a filter, but you can pass `null` if you don't want to use a filter.  With the Webkit API, passing `NULL` doesn't work.  If you call:

```
WebKitDOMTreeWalker* walker = webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker(doc, root, SHOW_ALL, NULL, false, err)
```

You get the error message:

> ** (webkit:3367): CRITICAL **: WebKitDOMTreeWalker* webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker(WebKitDOMDocument*,
>   WebKitDOMNode*, gulong, WebKitDOMNodeFilter*, gboolean, GError**):
>   assertion `filter' failed

So, the WebKit API won't accept a NULL pointer for the filter argument.  Evidently you need to pass an instance of a `WebKitDOMNodeFilter`.  Okay, again - this wouldn't be a problem either, except I've searched far and wide through the WebKit API, as well as Google, and I *can't find anyway to create a WebKitDOMNodeFilter* object!  The header file for [WebKitDOMNodeFilter.h](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=webkitdomnodefilter.h&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE4QFjAA&url=http://www.emdebian.org/~zumbi/tmp/webkit-1.6.1/build-2.0/DerivedSources/webkit/WebKitDOMNodeFilter.h&ei=5ngaUNvLHOT40gHryYCwBg&usg=AFQjCNH14toI2tpkYI20wmBhYNH8390xBA&cad=rja) doesn't expose any constructor for WebKitDOMNodeFilter.  It seems like the API doesn't ever expose anyway to actually construct a WebKitDOMNodeFilter object at all.

Yet... the API exposes many functions (like webkit_dom_document_create_tree_walker, and webkit_dom_document_create_node_iterator) which *require* a WebKitDOMNodeFilter.  So... is the API just incomplete right now?  Or, is there some way to create a Filter object which I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try casting your null to the `WebKitDOMNodeFilter` type by calling 
`WEBKIT_DOM_NODE_FILTER(null)`?

Comment: No, it still fails with an assertion failure.  Internally, WebKit GTK is checking if the pointer is NULL.